# vertical align inside divs contained in a div that represents a row

Tags: css

I've tried just about every vertical-align for div trick I can find and still not getting the results.  This is inside of an established responsive framework, so I've stripped it down to some inline CSS to show the issue.

[image]

```html
<div class="row uniform">
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;float:left;background:#CCC;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 1<br />
    line 2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;float:left;background:#a43c69;color:#FFF;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;float:left;background:#CCC;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 3
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;float:left;background:#a43c69;color:#FFF;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally boxes 2,3 and 4 go to the same height as box 1, and text in all boxes is vertically aligned in the middle.

row.uniform sets some margins, padding and a default vertical-align of baseline, but that's not effecting anything here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I removed your `float: left;` on all `div`.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row uniform">
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;background:#CCC;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 1<br />
    line 2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;background:#a43c69;color:#FFF;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;background:#CCC;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 3
  </div>
  <div style="clear:none;width:25%;background:#a43c69;color:#FFF;box-sizing:border-box;">
    box 4
  </div>
</div>
```

For those wondering about browser support, [it is supported on all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Comment: Thanks @DineiRockenbach!  The magical combination in the right order did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution and for more detailed information refer css [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

If you want to center align the content see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fcswuvpz/2/)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row div{
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style="background:#CCC;">
    box 1<br />
    line 2
  </div>
  <div style="background:#a43c69;">
    box 2
  </div>
  <div style="background:#CCC;">
    box 3
  </div>
  <div style="background:#a43c69;">
    box 4
  </div>
</div>
```